# Handle two different treatments on two calls

Tags: angular, angular8

I have two components. in the first, there is twice the same call to a page (select-person/{{person.id}})

**component1.html :**

```
            <td><a routerLink="select-person/{{person.id}}" class="person_link">{{person.nom}}</a></td> 
            <td>{{person.adress}}</td>
            <td>{{person.tel}}</td>

            <td>
              <a routerLink="select-person/{{person.id}}"><button class="xxx" title="Modifier"></button></a>

            </td>
          </tr>
```

In the second component, there are several elements in a page including a button

**component2.html :**

```
  <button class="classicButton" (click)="valid()">OK</button>
```

I would like that when I click on one of the two "routerlink", the OK button of the second component is for one activated and the other deactivated.

the button behavior of the second component must be different depending on the clicked routerlink

how could I do?

Comment: Use two different routes, or the same routes but with a different parameter or query parameter

Answer (score 1):

The most easer, as JbNizet say is defined severals routers for the same component

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'one', component: OneComponent,data:{component:'one'} },
  { path: 'onebis', component: OneComponent,data:{component:'one-bis'} },
];
```

In your component can ask about data in a ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.dataRouter=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data
  }
```

Another aproach, from Angular 7.2 is use "state", so the links can be like

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/one" 
     [state]="{ data: 'data 0' }">
     One - data 0
</a>
```

or you navigate like

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/one', { state: { data: 'data 0' } });
```

Then, from the component you as about the data, like

```
ngOnInit()
  {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap
      .pipe(map(() => window.history.state),
      take(1))
      .subscribe(res=>{
        this.data=res
      })
  }
```

But, in this case you need take account that to get the data, ouy need change the navigation. in the stackblitz, if you click on `One data-0`, and after `One data-1`, as is the same component you not get the data. See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8kjlw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fone.component.ts)

NOTE: window.history.date give you an additional propertie `navigationId`

NOTE2: I use take(1) to unsubscribe automatically

**Update** it's not about the question, but if we want to control the data sending in state from the **main.component**, we subscribe to this.router.events

```
  //In "main.component" (the component that has the <router-outlet>)
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart),
      map(() => this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
    ).subscribe(res=>{
      this.data=res
    })
  }
```